# What is the electrophile in Perkin's condensation reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, electrophilic-substitution

In Perkin's reaction, an aromatic aldehyde reacts with an acid anhydride to give an alpha-beta unsaturated aromatic acid. Which reactant is the electrophile and which one is the nucleophile?

Comment: Google is your friend! If you search "Perkin Reaction Mechanism" you will find your answer

Comment: @Waylander I did but I couldn't really get the answer to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reaction mechanism shown on the Wikipedia page for the Perkin Reaction is perfectly clear.

[image: mechanism of perkin reaction from wikipedia]

The first step is deprotonation of acetic anhydride by acetate anion.
The second step is nucleophilic attack by the anion of acetic anhydride on the aromatic aldehyde; thus the **aldehyde is the electrophile**.